# remove backslash in a file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I cannot remove a string containing a backslash with Powershell

```
(Get-Content $file.fullName).replace('\\mystring', ') | Set-Content $file.fullName
```

It works if I had to remove 'mystring' only

```
(Get-Content $file.fullName).replace('mystring', ') | Set-Content $file.fullName
```

But with a backslash no. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use a backtick (`) to escape the backslash.
Your command will look like

```
(Get-Content $file.fullName).replace('`\mystring', '') | Set-Content $file.fullName
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last `'` be `''`?